# Count the records with the same difference of two date columns Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Just wanted to ask what will be the query for my problem using rails and I'm using PostgreSQL for the database, let's say I have two columns one is start_date and end_date, I want to get only the records that have the same days difference when I subtract the two columns then count it. Example:

```
start_date | end_date
2017-06-01 | 2017-06-03
2017-07-25 | 2017-07-31
2017-09-05 | 2017-09-07
```

For this example, I have three records so when you get the difference of those three records this will be the result

first row is **2**

second row is **6**

third row is **2**

So the records that I only need to get are those two records with 2 days difference

Comment: What I understand is that you don't want only 2 days difference records?

Comment: No, what I want is to get only the records that have the same days difference, so in my example first row is 2 and third is 2 also so those two records will be the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try code:

```
diff = []

Model.select{|d| diff << (u.end_date - u.start_date).to_i }

max = diff.uniq.max_by{ |i| diff.count(i) }

result = Model.where("end_date - start_date = ?", max.to_s)

puts result
```

Comment: == 2 is for what?

Comment: 2 is just an example, the difference will be dynamic depends on the value of start_date and end_date, it is not fixed

Comment: @RyanAngelo the `== 2` can be easily substituted to a comparison with a variable.

Comment: @RyanAngelo 2 is for example, you can change it

Comment: @puneet18 sorry late reply, but there is no specific value to be match, what I need is get the difference of start_date and end_date then get the most often difference

Comment: @RyanAngelo vote my answer if it works for you. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> DB: PostgreSQL

You can use like this:

```
TableName.select("DATE_PART('day', end_date - start_date) as diff, count(*) as total").group("diff")
```

Comment: `.map{|d_t| [d_t.diff, d_t.total]}` to get list of the diffs and their totals

Answer (score 1):

**You can do like this**

> Example:

```
Model.all.each do |d|
    date = (d.end_date - d.start_date).to_i

    Model.where.not(id: d.id).each do |diff|
    date_diff = (diff.end_date - diff.start_date).to_i

         if (date==date_diff)
            puts date
         end
    end
end
```

Output depends on your `end_date` and `start_date` date format. I assume format like this `"2017-06-15 10:00:12"`